# SSH Connection with Python 3.0

Tags: python, file, ssh

How can I make an SSH connection in Python 3.0? I want to save a file on a remote computer where I have password-less SSH set up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend calling ssh as a subprocess.  It's reliable and portable.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'user@host', 'cat > %s' % filename],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(file_contents)
if proc.retcode != 0:
    ...
```

You'd have to worry about quoting the destination filename.  If you want more flexibility, you could even do this:

```
import subprocess
import tarfile
import io
tardata = io.BytesIO()
tar = tarfile.open(mode='w:gz', fileobj=tardata)
... put stuff in tar ...
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'user@host', 'tar xz'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(tardata.getvalue())
if proc.retcode != 0:
    ...
```

Comment: proc.communicate(tardata) says TypeError: must be string or buffer, not _io.BytesIO

Comment: then `tardata.getvalue()` has your answer

Answer (score 2):

You want all of the ssh-functionality implemented as a python library? Have a look at paramiko, although I think it's not ported to Python 3.0 (yet?).

If you can use an existing ssh installation you can use the `subprocess` way Dietrich described, or (another way) you could also use `pexpect` ([website here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

Comment: That OP asked for Python 3 option, but you mentioned paramiko anyways. But I agree the downvote is undeserved, given that's not all you said. Forgive me.

Comment: the [paramiko homepage](http://www.paramiko.org) now states that it also works with python 3.3+. Quote:"Paramiko is a Python (2.6+, 3.3+) implementation of the SSHv2 protocol [1], providing both client and server functionality..."

Answer (score 1):

First:

Two steps to login via ssh without password

in your terminal

```
[macm@macm ~]$  ssh-keygen
[macm@macm ~]$  ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.1.XX <== change
```

Now with python

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

cmd = 'uname -a'
stream = Popen(['ssh', 'root@192.168.1.XX', cmd],
                    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

rsp = stream.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
print(rsp)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might take a little work because "[twisted:conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/conch/documentation/howto/conch_client.html)" does not appear to have a 3.0 variant.

Answer (score 0):

I have written [Python bindings for libssh2](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/11/python-bindings-for-libssh2.html), that run on Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and **3**.

Answer (score 0):

[libssh2](https://github.com/wallunit/ssh4py) works great for Python 3.x.
See this Stack Overflow article 
[How to send a file using scp using python 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367020/how-to-send-a-file-using-scp-using-python-3-2)

Comment: No documentation available. Links on the pypi project page are dead!