# How to open an SSH tunnel using python?

Tags: python, django, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database using django.
The documentation specifies that it is required to open an SSH tunnel first to connect to the database.
Is there a python library that can open an SSH tunnel whenever certain settings are set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953477/ssh-connection-with-python-3-0

Comment: try https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)'s [forward](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py) functionality. For a paramiko overview, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101230075444/http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/).

Comment: The forward.py link isn't available.

Comment: The overview link points to an article that seems to have been removed. It's a shame, because there were a *lot* of other people who have linked to that article. You could try searching for copies of it, but I haven't had much luck. It's mentioned [here](https://github.com/qiwihui/pocket_readings/issues/33), and Google found [this](https://www.voidcn.com/article/p-rlufsmlb-bck.html), but I have not been able to confirm either alternative due to the Internet settings where I work.

Answer (score 9):

Try use [sshtunnel package](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel).

This is simple:

```
pip install sshtunnel
python -m sshtunnel -U vagrant -P vagrant -L :3306 -R 127.0.0.1:3306 -p 2222 localhost
```

Disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of this package.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code snippet for Python3 (but you should be able to retrofit it into Python2 without difficulty). It runs an SSH tunnel in a separate thread; then the main thread does something to get network traffic over the SSH tunnel.

In this example, the ssh tunnel forwards local port 2222 to port 80 on localhost. The main activity consists of running

```
curl http://localhost:2222
```

ie., fetching a webpage but from port 2222.

The class SshTunnel is initialized with 4 parameters, the local and remote port, the remote user, and the remote host. All it does, is start SSH in the following way:

```
ssh -N -L localport:remotehost:remoteport remoteuser@remotehost
```

In order to make this work, you'll need a password-less login for remoteuser@remotehost (via ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub that's known on the remote server). 
The thus running ssh tunnel is on one thread; the main task must be in another one. The ssh tunnel thread is marked as daemon so that it will automatically stop once the main activity terminates.

I didn't put in a full MySQL connectivity example because it should be self-explanatory. Once SshTunnel sets up a local TCP port, you can connect to it - be it via your MySQL client, curl, or whatever.

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading

class SshTunnel(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, localport, remoteport, remoteuser, remotehost):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.localport = localport      # Local port to listen to
        self.remoteport = remoteport    # Remote port on remotehost
        self.remoteuser = remoteuser    # Remote user on remotehost
        self.remotehost = remotehost    # What host do we send traffic to
        self.daemon = True              # So that thread will exit when
                                        # main non-daemon thread finishes

    def run(self):
        if subprocess.call([
            'ssh', '-N',
                   '-L', str(self.localport) + ':' + self.remotehost + ':' + str(self.remoteport),
                   self.remoteuser + '@' + self.remotehost ]):
            raise Exception ('ssh tunnel setup failed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tunnel = SshTunnel(2222, 80, 'karel', 'localhost')
    tunnel.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.call(['curl', 'http://localhost:2222'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little class that you can drop into your code:

```
import subprocess
import random
import tempfile

class SSHTunnel:

    def __init__(self, host, user, port, key, remote_port):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.port = port
        self.key = key
        self.remote_port = remote_port
        # Get a temporary file name
        tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        tmpfile.close()
        self.socket = tmpfile.name
        self.local_port = random.randint(10000, 65535)
        self.local_host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.open = False

    def start(self):
        exit_status = subprocess.call(['ssh', '-MfN',
            '-S', self.socket,
            '-i', self.key,
            '-p', self.port,
            '-l', self.user,
            '-L', '{}:{}:{}'.format(self.local_port, self.local_host, self.remote_port),
            '-o', 'ExitOnForwardFailure=True',
            self.host
        ])
        if exit_status != 0:
            raise Exception('SSH tunnel failed with status: {}'.format(exit_status))
        if self.send_control_command('check') != 0:
            raise Exception('SSH tunnel failed to check')
        self.open = True

    def stop(self):
        if self.open:
            if self.send_control_command('exit') != 0:
                raise Exception('SSH tunnel failed to exit')
            self.open = False

    def send_control_command(self, cmd):
        return subprocess.check_call(['ssh', '-S', self.socket, '-O', cmd, '-l', self.user, self.host])

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.stop()
```

And here's how you could use it, for example with MySQL (port 3306 usually):

```
with SSHTunnel('database.server.com', 'you', '22', '/path/to/private_key', '3306') as tunnel:
    print "Connected on port {} at {}".format(tunnel.local_port, tunnel.local_host)
```

Comment: I had to use `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` instead of `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=True`. Other than that, a useful little class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me.

Run this command in your terminal/CMD:
`pip install paramiko`

Then create a python file and add this code in that file:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('server_ip', username='root', password='password')
```

Now run the python file: `python yourfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest trying something like `pyngrok` to programmatically manage an `ngrok` tunnel for you? Full disclosure, I am the developer of it. SSH example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#open-a-tunnel), and Django example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#django), but it's as easy as installing `pyngrok`:

```
pip install pyngrok
```

and using it:

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

# <NgrokTunnel: "tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12345" -> "localhost:22">
ssh_tunnel = ngrok.connect(22, "tcp")
```

Or to expose your MySQL database:

```
# <NgrokTunnel: "tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12346" -> "localhost:3306">
mysql_tunnel = ngrok.connect(3306, "tcp")
```

Or to expose to Django dev server:

```
# <NgrokTunnel: "http://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:8000">
http_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8000)
```