# Send a string from python to server

Tags: python

I have a raspberry that measure some values through a Python script. I want to send all values to a server where I stored them in db.

What do you propose to use? (possibly an encrypted transfer).

The size of the strings has few bytes. Periods is 1-5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect straight to the remote database and update it, [here](http://banoffeepiserver.com/mysql/setting-up-remote-access-to-a-mysql-database.html) are some setup instructions

Or open an [SSH tunnel using paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364355/how-to-open-an-ssh-tunnel-using-python) from the raspi and do it that way I suppose. That will allow for an encrypted channel.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before, connect to the DB directly.

Otherwise, in case you already have a web application you want to/must use, you can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) it shows how to post data in several ways, e.g.

as form fields

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```

or json-encoded

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Requests supports use of HTTPS/[SSL](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).