# Python3 compatible ssh library

Tags: ssh, python-3.x

I checked the following, none of which work with Python 3:

- paramiko
- pexpect
- fabric
- some custom made scripts

What would you recommend to use for SSH operations like:

- password login
- key based authentication
- file transfer
- remote command execution

I'd like to avoid `subprocess.Popen` as this causes some headaches while multitreading.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/953477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python bindings for libssh2](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/11/python-bindings-for-libssh2.html)  now supports python3 as well

Thanks to @aix