# How to initiate ssh connection with Python 3

Tags: ssh, python-3.x, connection

Is there any easy way to initiate ssh connection with Python 3 without using `popen`? I would like to achieve password and password less authentication.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH Connection with Python 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953477/ssh-connection-with-python-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Python bindings for libssh2](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/11/python-bindings-for-libssh2.html). I believe they are compatible with Python 3.

Comment: I have checked that few weeks back, there was no support for python3 but I can see latest updates from Feb 16th should have already been supported. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Paramiko does not work with Python 3.x yet

Answer (score -2):

I use the paramiko module for all ssh related stuff. Its really convenient.

http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

However I do not know if it works with python3.