# How can I send a file from one pc to another ip address to a pecific path in it using python?

Tags: python

How can I send a file from one pc to another ip address to a specific path in it using python? 
I don't need full client-server, I just need to send the file.

Comment: You can use the [`socket` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

Comment: well it's sent on closed net..

Answer (score 1):

File transfer, at least if it's not the store-on-floppy-and-carry-to-other-computer kind, ***by definition*** requires a listening component (/process) on the receiving computer and a sending process on the transmitting computer.  That is client-server ***by definition***.  So your saying "I don't need full client-server" most of all suggests that you have hardly any clue of what you're asking for.

You're clearly asking "how can I get this simple job done in two or at most three simple commands" and that's just not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I always use ssh to send files to other computers. It is possible to use ssh from python. How to do that is explained in this question:

[SSH Connection with Python 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953477/ssh-connection-with-python-3-0)